# Get HarvestSource for a package in CKAN

Tags: ckan

Based on the id of a dataset package, how do I figure out if the package was harvested, by which harvester and what the base URL of that harvester is?

Something along the lines of:

```python
guid = '65715c6e-bbaf-3def-982b-3b5156272da7'
harvest_source = getHarvestSource(guid)

if (harvest_source):
  type = harvest_source.type() # whatever was set as the name attribute for this harvester class
  base_url = harvest_source.url() # whatever was set as the URL in the admin interface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried it, but from reading the [model](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/blob/master/ckanext/harvest/model/__init__.py) I expect something like this:

```
from ckan.model import Package

id = u'65715c6e-bbaf-3def-982b-3b5156272da7'
dataset = model.Package.get(id)
dataset_was_harvested = bool(len(dataset.harvest_objects) > 0)
if dataset_was_harvested:
    ho = dataset.harvest_objects[0]  # there's not usually more than 1
    source = ho.source  # i.e. the harvest source is "the harvester"
    source.url  # i.e. the harvester's base url
    source.type # is also useful
```

Comment: Great, that works! For completeness' sake, the harvester's type (`name` attribute from `ISpatialHarvester.info()`)  can be retrieved with `source.type`.

Comment: One more thing: `dataset_was_harvested = bool(dataset.harvest_objects > 0)` should be `dataset_was_harvested = bool(len(dataset.harvest_objects) > 0)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I've added these changes to the answer